# Perl/DBI selectrow_array scope confusion

Tags: perl, dbi

So, I've got a list of files and I'm checking a database table to see if an entry exists and pull the id and destination filename.  If not there, insert an entry and repull the entry (note the id is auto increment so no matter I have to do a second query.)

The issue is when I re-pull the query after the insert, the variable it's going into is lexical (i think that's the correct wording) and once I leave the scope of the if (!defined) block, it loses its value.

```
#lookup file db entry
my ($fileId, $destFilename) = $dbh->selectrow_array("select fileId, destFilename from myTable where sourceFilename = '$file'");
if (! defined $fileId) {
    # calculate out what the destination filename should be here..
    # add missing entry into table
    ($fileId, $destFilename) = $dbh->selectrow_array("select fileId, destFilename from myTable where sourceFilename = '$file'");
    print Dumper $destFilename;
}
print Dumper $destFilename;
```

This will result in:

```
$VAR1 = "correctfilenamehere"
$VAR1 = undef
```

I have tried defining the variables before assigning them via the selectrow_array call.  I've tried changing above from my to our for these variables.  I'm confused on why it's doing this.

Also to note, this code is within another block so those variables are already lexical to that scope.  I had presumed they would be available in the child blocks, but it's not really working that way as far as I can see.

Comment: This is not how scopes work; your code as written will not do this. Something else is going on.

Comment: As a note, your `$file` parameter should be bound as a parameter and not interpolated into the string, this is [very dangerous](https://xkcd.com/327/). `$dbh->selectrow_array("select fileId, destFilename from myTable where sourceFilename = ?", undef, $file);`

Comment: As for the binding, if it involved any input from anything other then the filenames in the file system, I'd agree completely.  However, this should be fairly safe in a confined environment when only using filenames from the file system as input.

Comment: Safe from malicious activity yes, but filenames can easily break the query. Binding parameters is the simplest and best approach in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not exhibit the behaviour you describe.

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

   sub f { $_[0] ? (4, "abc") : () }

   my ($fileId, $destFilename) = f(0);
   if (!defined $fileId) {
       ($fileId, $destFilename) = f(1);
       print Dumper $destFilename;
   }

   print Dumper $destFilename;
'
$VAR1 = 'abc';
$VAR1 = 'abc';
```

You could get the described bahaviour if you introduced a new variable with the same name.

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

   sub f { $_[0] ? (4, "abc") : () }

   my ($fileId, $destFilename) = f(0);
   if (!defined $fileId) {
       my ($fileId, $destFilename) = f(1);
       print Dumper $destFilename;
   }

   print Dumper $destFilename;
'
$VAR1 = 'abc';
$VAR1 = undef;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, a bit of code was making a lexical variable of the same name and I wasn't noticing, so the parent $destFilename was being replaced with a local variant.

Comment: Sadly it's not possible to automatically detect such masking when it occurs in a nested scope, since that's a perfectly reasonable (though potentially confusing) coding practice. There is a warning if you mask a lexical in the same scope.

Comment: @Grinnz, Re "*it's not possible to automatically detect such masking when it occurs in a nested scope*", I believe that `perlcritic` has a rule for that. (I wish `use warnings;` would be sufficient. How often do you want to use two vars with the same name in the same scope.)

Comment: @ikegami what I mean is, it's not possible to tell if it was intended. It is rare that it would be indeed, but it happens

Comment: @Grinnz, I've never seen it. And if I did, I would say "Are you crazy? Use a different name!" Maybe if one was top-level, and one was in a sub. That can happen due to refactoring. But two same-named vars in a sub? That stinks and should warn.